# Getting data that is nested in a mongoldb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mean-stack

I have written an api for a user where it store his/her data for avatar and user information have nested it inside another doc.
Here is my model.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['creator', 'admin'],
        default: 'creator'
    },
    tokens: Array,
    profile: {
        name: String,
        gender: String,
        location: String,
        picture: {
            data: Buffer, contentType: String
        }
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

My `GET` method is.

```
exports.getUsers = (req, res) => {
    User.find({}).lean().exec(function (err,docs) {
      return res.json(docs);
    }) 
}
```

On postman when I query the data I get this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59d665c3acbde702b47d3987",
        "updatedAt": "2017-10-07T17:23:00.498Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-10-05T17:02:59.526Z",
        "email": "me@mail.com",
        "password": "$2a$05$z1mRUWqqUfM8wKMU/y9/sOLssAKcV7ydxi0XJyTR1d3BI2X7SSsoy",
        "tokens": [],
        "role": "admin",
        "__v": 0,
        "profile": {
            "name": "F.name L.name",
            "gender": "Female",
            "location": "my place",
            "avatar": {
                "contentType": "image/png",
                "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAaYAAAFmCAYAAAAmm....."
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Am stack on rendering profile detail to angular4 for the email it shows without any issue.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of getProfile">
  <h3>{{item.profile.name}}</h3>
  <h4>{{item.email}}</h4>
  <img src="{{item.profile.avator}}" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: according to ur json img html should be `<img [src]="item.profile.avatar.data" alt="">`

Comment: Thanks it's working.